# Is Inner product continuous when one arg is fixed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, inner-products

In a inner product space with inner product $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$ and real or complex line as its base field, for each point $x$ in the space, is $\langle x,-\rangle$ continuous function on the second argument, and is $\langle - ,x\rangle$ continuous function on the first argument? "Continuous" is defined respect to the topology induced by the inner product.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: It's a continuous function of **both** arguments!

Comment: You mean continuous wrt the product topology?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/428945/161825

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes.

Fix x in the inner product space, and let $f(y) = \langle y, x \rangle$ denote the inner product function.  Note that this is a linear functional -- that is, it is linear in y, and maps vectors to scalars.

It is a well-known theorem that linear functionals are continuous (on the entire space) if and only if they are bounded.  Here, "bounded" means that there exists a constant M such that $|f(y)| \leq M|y|$ for all y in the space.

That the inner product functional is bounded now follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality: $|f(y)| \leq |x||y|.$

Comment: In general, if X and Y are real/complex normed vector spaces and T: X -> Y is a linear operator, then the following are equivalent: (1) T is continuous on X; (2) T is continuous at 0; (3) T is bounded; (4) T maps bounded subsets to bounded subsets; (5) T is Lipschitz continuous on X.

Answer (score 20):

Fix $x$. We have $|\langle x,y\rangle - \langle x,z\rangle| = |\langle x,y-z\rangle|\leq ||x||||y-z||$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. This gives you easily that $\langle x,-\rangle\colon \mathbf{V}\to\mathbb{F}$ is not only continuous, but uniformly continuous. Similarly for $\langle -,x\rangle$.

Comment: Great, +1, thank you. I like this proof : ) Gives me an application of Cauchy Schwarz *and* answers my question about whether the inner product is continuous.

Comment: @arturomagidin Can you please clarify why the inequality you have derived using Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality shows that the mapping is uniformly continuous? Is it because we can choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{||x||}$ to be as needed to satisfy the epsilon condition?

Comment: @texmex The equation shows that the function is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity?wprov=sfti1). For $x\neq 0$ you can take that value. For $x=0$, any value of $\delta\gt0$ works.

Answer (score 13):

If we define $T_x v = \langle v,x\rangle$ then $T_x$ is a linear functional. Since an inner product induces a norm, and thus it is continuous if and only if it is bounded on the unit circle.

And so $|T_x v | = |\langle v,x\rangle | \le \|v\|\cdot \|x\|$ and for $v$ on the unit circle, i.e. $\|v\| = 1$ we have that $T_x$ is indeed bounded and therefore continuous.

The proof is similar if you fix the left argument, however it may not be a linear functional if it is a complex vector space, but rather antilinear (that is linear up to conjugation). The norm is unaffected by that, though, so it's not a big step to overcome.

Comment: Asaf... You and analysis?

Comment: If the thread was already bumped... correction past mistakes sounds like a good plan. :-)

Comment: Why is is sufficient to analyze the unit circle?

Comment: @mavavilj: Things scale up/down to the unit circle. And scaling is continuous.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you further assume that the vector space is finite?

Comment: @mavavilj: No...

Comment: @mavavilj: I'm not sure which RHS you mean.

Comment: @mavavilj: Also, where do I mention "dimension" in the whole story?

Comment: Then how is the R.H.S. finite?  In 2nd paragraph. If it's bounded, it must be finite?

Comment: @mavavilj: Do you understand what does it mean for a linear operator to be bounded on the unit circle? Perhaps you should look up the relevant definitions. Finiteness is irrelevant.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My notes have a lemma: Linear operator $T:E \rightarrow F$ is bounded iff its norm is finite. In the C-S the norm of the operator is on the left. But is the right finite so that the left can be? Further the lemma says to find a $C < \infty$ s.t. $\|Tx\|_F \leq C\|x\|_E$ $\implies$ $\|T\| \leq C$. So maybe you did  $C=1$? However, since it seems like you fixed $x$, rather than $v$, then should $\|x\|=1$? Or which one is your parameter?

Comment: @mavavilj: Yes, the norm is finite. What does that have to do with the dimension?

Comment: The norm definition I have allows the norm to attain values in $[0,\infty)$. I read that this includes $\infty$, no? It's open in the right end, but this is often the case when marking for "goes to infinity", since the infinity cannot be really attained. On the other hand, another reference says that in normed spaces $\| \cdot \|$ is always assumed to not attain infinity, it always has finite value.

Comment: @mavavilj: Where in my answer do you see the word "finite" or "infinite"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm asking, how would one distinguish between them, given your answer. Or how your answer relates to the notes that I have, which say that norms are always finite. While vector spaces might be infinite dimensional. Your answer leaves open as to whether the R.H.S. could be infinite? So I just want to check, what definitions your answer uses.

Comment: @mavavilj: The RHS is never infinite. It's a real number and all real numbers are finite. I'm still not sure what that has to do with the dimension of the space.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well since the inputs to norms are vectors, then if the vector space is infinite dimensional, then the norm could be infinite? Particularly e.g. in $\|\cdot\|_2$? Since one'd have an infinite positive sum inside the square root?

Comment: @mavavilj: Norms and inner products are abstractly defined.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What does that mean? Surely one can do your proof for finite and infinite cases separately. Also, what use is an "abstract definition" if it would fall apart, if one has to consider specific cases?

Comment: @mavavilj I think it's time to end this discussion. It's not the point of the comments.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way is to show that it is a convex function, and then use the theorem that says that if a convex function defined on a convex set, then the function is continuous in every interior point. Since we are talking about $\Bbb{R}^n$, then it is true for all points because $\Bbb{R}^n$ is a convex and open set.