# Continuity of scalar product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

In a Hilbert space $H$ with inner product and associated norm, why would if $\|x-x_n\| \longrightarrow 0$ and $\|y-y_n\| \longrightarrow 0$ also $\langle x_n,y_n\rangle \longrightarrow\langle x,y\rangle$?

I understand that by Cauchy-Schwarz $\lvert\langle x-x_n,y-y_n\rangle\rvert \leq \|x-x_n\|\cdot\|y-y_n\|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ but how do I get to $\lvert\langle x,y\rangle-\langle x_n,y_n\rangle \rvert\longrightarrow 0$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $E$ be an inner product space and $\lim x_n = x$, $\lim y_n = y$. Is it true that $\lim \langle x_n, y_n \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320057/let-e-be-an-inner-product-space-and-lim-x-n-x-lim-y-n-y-is-it-true) Note that your assumption that $H$ is complete is useless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint:

$$|\langle x,y\rangle-\langle x_n,y_n\rangle|=|\langle x,y\rangle-\langle x_n,y\rangle+\langle x_n,y\rangle-\langle x_n,y_n\rangle|;$$

Grouping the terms, using the triangular inequality for $|\cdot|$ and Cauchy-Schwarz helps.