# Computing $DF(c),$ where $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ and $F:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R, F(x,y)=\cos(\langle f(x)\cdot y,f(y)\cdot x\rangle)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> Let $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ be a differentiable function and define $F:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ by $$F(x,y)=\cos(\langle f(x)\cdot y,f(y)\cdot x\rangle ).$$ Express $DF$ by $Df$.

**My work:**

Since $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\cong\Bbb R^{2n}$ and write $((x_1,\ldots,x_n),(y_1,\ldots,y_n))=(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ and denote by $\pi_1,\pi_2:\Bbb R^{2n}\to\Bbb R^n$ the projections on the first and second $n$ coordinates, respectively. Projections are linear (with matrix representations $\begin{bmatrix}I_n& 0_n\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0_n&I_n\end{bmatrix}\in M_{n,2n}(\Bbb R)$), so they are equal to their differentials at every point.

We can then rewrite, $F=\cos\circ g,\space g=\langle (f\circ\pi_1)\cdot\pi_2,(f\circ\pi_2)\cdot\pi_1\rangle$

and

$\begin{aligned}DF(x_0,y_0)&=-\sin(g(x_0,y_0))Dg(x_0,y_0)\\&=-\sin(\langle f(x_0)y_0,f(y_0)x_0\rangle Dg(x_0,y_0)\\&=-\sin(f(x_0)f(y_0)\langle x_0,y_0\rangle)Dg(x_0,y_0)\end{aligned}$

First, I computed $$\begin{aligned}D(f\circ \pi_i)(x_0,y_0)&=Df(\pi_i(x_0,y_0))\circ D\pi_i(x_0,y_0)\\&=Df(\pi_i(x_0,y_0))\pi_i\end{aligned}$$

Now, let $h_1:\Bbb R^{2n}\to\Bbb R^n, h_1=(f\circ\pi_1)\cdot\pi_2.$

Then $$\begin{aligned}Dh_1(x_0,y_0)&=\pi_2(x_0,y_0)\cdot D(f\circ\pi_1)(x_0,y_0)+(f\circ\pi_1)(x_0,y_0)\cdot D\pi_2(x_0,y_0)\\&=y_0\cdot Df(x_0)\pi_1+f(x_0)\pi_2.
\end{aligned}$$

We can, analogously define $h_2:\Bbb R^{2n}\to\Bbb R^n$ by $h_2=(f\circ\pi_2)\cdot\pi_1$

For $g,$ I'm going to use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4330365/942722): if $F,G:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m,$ are differentiable, then $$D(\langle F,G\rangle)(c)=G(c)^TDf(c)+F(c)^TDg(c)$$
$$\begin{aligned}D(\langle (f\circ\pi_1)\cdot\pi_2,(f\circ\pi_2)\cdot\pi_1\rangle)(x_0,y_0)&=((f\circ\pi_2)\cdot\pi_1)(x_0,y_0)^TD((f\circ\pi_1)\cdot\pi_2)(x_0,y_0)+((f\circ\pi_1)\cdot\pi_2)(x_0,y_0)^TD((f\circ\pi_2)\cdot\pi_1))(x_0,y_0)\\&=f(y_0)x_0^T(y_0Df(x_0)\pi_1+f(x_0)\pi_2)+f(x_0)y_0^T(x_0Df(y_0)\pi_2+f(y_0)\pi_1)\\&=f(y_0)\langle x_0,y_0\rangle Df(x_0)\pi_1+f(x_0)f(y_0)x_0^T\pi_2+f(x_0)\langle x_0,y_0\rangle Df(y_0)\pi_2+f(x_0)f(y_0)y_0^T\pi_1\end{aligned}$$

so we obtain
$DF(x_0,y_0)=\color{red}{-\sin(f(x_0)f(y_0)\langle f(x_0),f(y_0)\rangle)}\color{blue}{(f(y_0)\langle x_0,y_0\rangle Df(x_0)\pi_1+f(x_0)f(y_0)x_0^T\pi_2+f(x_0)\langle x_0,y_0\rangle Df(y_0)\pi_2+f(x_0)f(y_0)y_0^T\pi_1)}$

Is there any mistake in my computation or a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the scalar
$a = f(\mathbf{x}) f(\mathbf{y}) \mathbf{x}^T  \mathbf{y}$
It follows
$$
dF = -\sin(a) da
$$
It remains to compute
\begin{eqnarray}
da &=&
[Df(\mathbf{x}) f(\mathbf{y}) \mathbf{x}^T  \mathbf{y}+
f(\mathbf{x}) f(\mathbf{y}) \mathbf{y}] d\mathbf{x}+
[Df(\mathbf{y}) f(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{x}^T  \mathbf{y}+
f(\mathbf{x}) f(\mathbf{y}) \mathbf{x}] d\mathbf{y}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: So, you viewd $f(\mathbf y)\mathbf y$ and $f(\mathbf x)\mathbf{x}^T$ as constants for $d\mathbf x$ and $d\mathbf y$ respectively as in partial differentiation?

Comment: Sure, these two variables are assumed to be independent in this derivation.