# If $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous, then $\{x\in X: f(x)\cdot y\leq 0\}$ closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $f: X \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous on a metric space $X$ and let 
$y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to prove that $A=\{x\in X: f(x)\cdot y\leq 0\}$ is closed.

Here is my proof, which I think needs some details filled in:

Let $x\in X$ be a limit point of $A$. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. Since $f$ is continuous, then $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence, $f(x_n)\cdot y \rightarrow f(x) \cdot y$ $\,$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $f(x_n)\cdot y \leq 0$ for all $n$ then this implies that $f(x)\cdot y \leq 0$ (this is the part I am not sure whether it requires details filled in). Therefore, $x\in A$. That is, $A$ is closed.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(x)=f(x)\cdot y$ is continuous, $(-\infty,0]$ is closed, so its preimage $g^{-1}((-\infty,0])$ is also closed.

Comment: Thank you. I had come up with this proof after I came up with the one above. The one I wrote above came more naturally to me. I just wanted to know if the proof I wrote requires additional details to be filled in.

Comment: Your initial solution is good enough. And yes, you can go to the limit in $f(x_n)\cdot y \le 0$ (after all you are in $\mathbb R$ on the LHS)

Comment: maybe the only detail that you might fill in is that the dot product is continuous (in both arguments)

Comment: How do I show that $f(x)\cdot y$ is continuous? Any small hints? Thanks!

Comment: Look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428945/continuity-of-scalar-product) for example (Cauchy-Schwarz)

Comment: $|f(x_n)\cdot y-f(x)\cdot y|=|(f(x_n)-f(x))\cdot y|\le\lVert f(x_n)-f(x)\rVert_2\lVert y\rVert_2\rightarrow 0$ since $f$ is continuous. Or just prove separately that the dot product is continuous (as shown in the link), then say that $f(x)\cdot y$ is a composition of two continuous functions, which is continuous.