# Derivative of dot product

Tags: derivatives

Let $\frac{dy}{dt}=Ay+g(y)$ and consider $\lVert y(t)\rVert^2=\langle y,y\rangle$. I would like to prove that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\langle y,y\rangle= 2\langle\frac{dy}{dt},y\rangle.
$$

To do so, I made the following start:

$$
\langle y+\Delta y,y+\Delta y\rangle=\langle y,y\rangle+2\langle\Delta y,y\rangle+o(\lVert \Delta y\rVert)\text{ as }\Delta y\to 0.
$$

So the derivative seems to arise from the summand
$$
2\langle\Delta y,y\rangle.
$$
But how? It seems to be
$$
2\langle\Delta y,y\rangle=2\langle\dot{y},y\rangle\Delta y?
$$

Comment: Well, to keep your notation, actually $$\Delta y=\dot{y}\Delta t+o(\Delta t)$$ which is what you want, since you are deriving in $t$. The existence of $\dot{y}$ implies that $o(\Vert \Delta y\Vert)=o(\Delta t)$ as well.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Did not get it, sorry. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You are deriving in $t$. So, at some point, you'll have to expand it as a function of $t$, not of $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative $\frac{d}{dt}\left<y(t),y(t)\right>$ is defined as $$\frac{d}{dt}\left<y(t),y(t)\right> \equiv \lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta t}\left[\left<y(t+\Delta t),\,y(t+\Delta t)\right> - \left<y(t),y(t)\right>\right]$$

To prove the result in the question we can try to rewrite the right hand side above (forget about the limit until the end) [using the laws of an inner-product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html)

- Bi-linearity: $\left<x+y,z\right>=\left<x,z\right> + \left<y,z\right>$
- Multiplication by scalar: $c\left<x,z\right>=\left<cx,z\right>$ for $c\in\mathbb{C}$.
- Symmetry: $\left<x,y\right>=\left<y,x\right>$

to try to put it on a form resembling $2\left<\frac{dy(t)}{dt},y(t)\right>$. Doing this we find

$$\frac{1}{\Delta t}\left[\left<y(t+\Delta t),\,y(t+\Delta t)\right> - \left<y(t),y(t)\right>\right] = \left<\frac{y(t+\Delta t) - y(t)}{\Delta t},y(t)\right>  + \left<y(t),\frac{y(t+\Delta t)-y(t)}{\Delta t}\right> + \Delta t\left<\frac{y(t+\Delta t) - y(t)}{\Delta t},\frac{y(t+\Delta t) - y(t)}{\Delta t}\right>$$

And from this form it's just a matter of taking the limit $\Delta t\to 0$ to arrive at the result (you will need to use that "the limit of a product equals the product of the limits" for the last term). Also note that the inner-product is a [continuous function in both arguments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/is-inner-product-continuous-when-one-arg-is-fixed) so the limit can be moved inside the brackets.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice proof. But my original problem is, that the professor just wrote $\langle y+\Delta y,y+\Delta y\rangle=\langle y,y\rangle+2\langle\Delta y,y\rangle+o(\lVert \Delta y\rVert)\text{ as }\Delta y\to 0$ on the blackboard and only from this, he concluded that $2\langle \dot{y},y\rangle$ is the derivative. I could not understand it that quickly and therefore I now try to understand it how it can be seen so fast.

Comment: @Salamo Your professor does basically the same as me here, but with a more casual notation. I tried to make it a bit more basic so that all steps that go into it would be more visible. The full equation you have above (using the laws I mentioned above) is: $\left<y+\Delta y,y+\Delta y\right> = \left<y,y\right> +2\left<\Delta y,y\right> + \left<\Delta y,\Delta y\right>$. The last term equals $||\Delta y||^2$ making it $o(|\Delta y||)$. Now subtracting $\left<y,y\right>$ from both sides, dividing by $\Delta x$ and taking the limit gives the result.

Comment: Am a bit confused since he does not use $\Delta t$ (what makes more sense to me), but $\Delta y$.

Comment: I guess, with $\Delta y$, he means $y(t+\Delta t)-y(t)$?

Comment: Your professor is doing a quick-and-dirty derivation. That is fine if one understands what is going on, but otherwise it's easy to get confused. There is indeed a $\Delta t$ there, but it's 'under the cover'. The term $\Delta y$ is the change in $y$ when we change $t$ by $\Delta t$.

Comment: @Salamo Exactly!

Answer (score 3):

It is straight forward:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} (y \cdot y) 
&= \frac{d}{dt}\sum_i y_i^2 \\
&= \sum_i 2 y_i \dot{y_i} \\
&= 2 \sum_i y_i \dot{y_i} \\
&= 2(y \cdot \dot{y})
\end{align}